# Odd behaviour reading an entire collection using Reactivemongo in Play Framework 2

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo

I have the following code:

```
  def all: String = {

    val query = BSONDocument("name" -> BSONDocument("$ne" -> "allDocs"))

    val cursor = carsCollection.find(query).cursor[BSONDocument]
    Logger.debug("Before cursor")
    cursor.enumerate.apply(Iteratee.foreach {
      doc =>
        Logger.debug("found document: " + doc.getAs[BSONString]("name").get.value)
        //Logger.debug("found document: " + doc.getAs[BSONString]("area").get.value)
    })
    "Ok"
  }
```

When I run this code the play console shows the field `"name"` of 12 different documents coming from `mongodb`. When I uncomment the second Logger call, the system prints only one name and it stops. The field `"area"` exists in the db without problems.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No error? Are you sure that your area field is always filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `doc.getAs[BSONString]("area").get.value` throws some exception.

You should test if there is a value and what is the type of the value to be sure:

```
cursor.enumerate.apply(Iteratee.foreach { doc =>
  // ...
  doc.getAs[BSONString]("area") match {
    case Some(BSONString(area)) => Logger.debug(s"area is BSONString of value = $area")
    case None => Logger.debug("area does not exist or is not a BSONString"
  }
}
```

The `getAs[BSONString]` method returns an `Option[BSONString]`. If there is a value, but this value could not be parsed as a `BSONString` – in other words, when the value is not a BSONString but rather a BSONInteger, BSONLong, BSONDocument, etc. – then `None` is returned. Since you call `get` on it, without checking if the option is defined or not, it might throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

Another way of doing this:

```
cursor.enumerate.apply(Iteratee.foreach { doc =>
  // ...
  doc.get("area") match {
    case Some(BSONString(area)) => Logger.debug(s"area is a BSONString of value = $area")
    case Some(otherBSONValue) => Logger.debug(s"area exists but is not a BSONString: $otherBSONValue")
    case None => Logger.debug("area does not exist or is not a BSONString"
  }
}
```

If there is an exception in your iteratee, the final future may be in error.

```
val future = cursor.enumerate |>>> Iteratee.foreach { doc =>
  Logger.debug("found document: " + doc.getAs[BSONString]("name").get.value)
  Logger.debug("found document: " + doc.getAs[BSONString]("area").get.value)
}
future.onComplete {
  case Success(_) => Logger.debug("successful!")
  case Failure(e) => Logger.debug(s"there was an exception! ${e.getMessage}")
}
```

Comment: You are totally right. The piece of code that I pasted was just a test, but the issue was the datatype. Of course the area wasn't string, it is a BSONDouble. Thanks for your help!